# Layers became invisible on the Layer Pane after using TimeManager plugin in QGIS

Tags: qgis, timemanager, general-transit-feed-specification, transit

I am working on a transit map, using TimeManager to interpolate the points and animate them according to the *timedate* fields.

After interpolating a couple of layers, out of the 10 available, and saving the file, I cannot see any of my layers anymore.
[image: view of the layers pane and main window]

As you can see on the bottom right hand side, the timestamp is still there, after the saving-closing-opening process.

Adding further information, the live layer styling pane, effectively shows the available layers, as you can see here:
[image: live layer styling pane]

The 10 working layers (in Geopackage format), the 2 interpolated layers, source files and some background layers.

Trying to investigate further, checking the TimeManager log, I found these *critical* errors, which are clearly related to the main problem of the layers disappearing from the layer pane:

[image: TimeManager log errors]

Reached this point, I am completely clueless. The layers are there, although they are invisible in the layers pane and in the main windows. Visible and editable, however, in the styles pane.

Any idea on how to overcome this error and bring them back? In case it is needed, I can provide you with the source files.

**Small update:** after deleting the two layers created by the interpolation, and clicking on the zoom to layer button, it suddenly shows all the layers on the viewport; however, they are still missing from the layer pane.

Comment: Did you consider using the new Temporal Controller instead of the (outdated) Time Manager Plugin? See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/438399/interpolating-points-with-qgis-native-temporal-controller In any case, it would be good if you could share at least a sample of your data + project to reproduce. Otherwise, its difficult to help.

Comment: I didn't consider using the new Temporal Controller simply because it doesn't have the Interpolation function as a native functionality.
Later on today I will try to share the dataset and the project, in case you want to fiddle with it and check if it works on your side.